# Find the number of ordered pairs $(m, n)$ of positive integers such that $mn = 2010020020010002$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

No calculators allowed, so I don't know how to approach this problem, and I wonder if there's an easier way than factoring it all out by hand.

Comment: First of all, it's the same as the number of divisors. Now how to find those... (Mathematica gives the prime factorization as $2 \times 915917 \times 10972719253$ so...)

Comment: @MichaelT That's actually the factorization of the number with $4$ zeros before the very last $2$.

Comment: @T.Bongers You're right, my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Michael T noticed, you need to find the number of divisors of your number and to do so,  you can fin the prime factorization of the number. Looking at the number it is clearly divisible by $2$ so
$$k =  2010020020010002 = 2 \times1005010010005001$$
Now, the last factor present a interesting patern. if you look at the numbers that apear at the position multiples of 3 (starting with 0) you have
$$1 \ \ 5 \ \ 10 \ \  10 \ \ 5 \ \ 1$$
tha are combinatorial numbers(a row of Pascal triangle)
so $$1005010010005001 = \binom{5}{5} (1000)^5 + \binom{5}{4} (1000)^4 + \binom{5}{3} (1000)^3 + \binom{5}{2} (1000)^2 + \binom{5}{1} (1000)^1 + \binom{5}{0} = (1000 + 1)^5$$
by Binomial theorem and $1001 = 7\times 11\times 13$. So
$$k = 2\times(1001)^5 = 2\times 7^5 \times 11^5 \times 13^5$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2010020020010002=2^{1}*7^{5}*11^{5}*13^{5}$$,then $answer=(1+1)*(5+1)*(5+1)*(5+1)=432$